# How could this constructor code be improved?

Tags: objective-c, constructor, cocoa

How could this constructor code be improved? I feel like I'm not doing something optimally here...

```
@interface JGProduct : NSObject {
    NSString *identifier;
}

+(JGProduct *)productWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_;
-(JGProduct *)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_;

@end

@implementation JGProduct

+(JGProduct *)productWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier_] autorelease];
}

-(JGProduct *)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _identifier = [identifier_ retain];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**id or JGProduct return type?**

I see a lot of people writing

```
-(id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
```

instead - why is this?

Surely any subclass of JGProduct would be exchangeable for the superclass... Or should I be returning something that is `id` but conforms to a protocol (if present)?

**JGProduct or [self class] in initialiser?**

I also see this:

```
+(JGProduct *)productWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
    return [[[JGProduct alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier_] autorelease];
}
```

or

```
+(JGProduct *)productWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier_] autorelease];
}
```

Why would someone write either of these? The top one surely would not make the right kind of object if ran by a subclass. And what's the difference between `self` and `[self class]` if you're in a class method?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why `-init...` should be declared to return `id`**

Imagine you have class A and its subclass B sharing the same designated initializer, `initWithString:`.

```
@interface A : NSObject
-(A *) initWithString: (NSString *) string;
@end

@interface B : A
-(B *) initWithString: (NSString *) string;
@end
```

As you can see, the declarations have a conflicting return type, which unavoidably causes a compiler warning. You can trivially fix it by changing the methods to return `id`, which, given Objective-C dynamic typing, doesn't change anything about how these methods work. So it has become a well-established, but not as well-understood, tradition.

**Why class initializers should use `self` rather than the class name**

As you correctly noticed, using `JGProduct` instead of `self` will allocate an instance of `JGProduct` for any subclass, which is not what you want in 99% cases.

**Why write `+[JGProduct productWithIdentifier:]`?**

Most of the time, it's just a shortcut to `alloc`, `init` and `autorelease` to make calling code more readable. However, these initializers may be much more complicated and more efficient when implemented in *class clusters*. When you write a class cluster, you have one public superclass and several private subclasses. In such cases the superclass's `alloc` has to return a placeholder object which will allocate and instantiate an object of the right subclass in its `init...` implementation. The class initializer, on the other hand, can immediately return an already inited object of the right subclass.